# Cordova Ajax Bad Request

Tags: ajax, cordova, heroku

I've got a simple server app running on Heroku that I'm making ajax calls to from a Cordova app. I've setup CORS on the server app and I can call the server from my browser without any problems. However, when I call the server using the exact same code from within Cordova I get a Bad Request error!!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://{myserver}/{function}',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { mydata... },
    success: function(resp){ alert("success"); },
    error: function(err) { alert(err.statusText); }
});
```

I've tried adding `crossDomain: true` and `dataType: 'jsonp'`, it makes no difference. I've also checked that all domains are whitelisted in Cordova `<access origin="*" />`

Why can't I access the server from Cordova when I can access it from my browser?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The reason was that I has a misspelling in `data: { ... }` so one of the parameters was missing.